# How can we view past civievents in the events summary dashboard on civi? we can only see current and future ones

Tags: civievent, dashboard

We want to see past events in our civi events dashboard. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE! I don't think you can configure the dashboard, but you can get a similar result by using the Event Participants report and searching by event them name and grouping by name. And you can filter by a specific period. You can save this as a new report.

Comment: Just to add that you could add the event report to the CiviCRM dashboard as a dashlet. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/reporting/everyday-tasks/#reports-on-your-dashboard